# tableView function runs before array is populated

Tags: swift, auth0

I am trying to populate a Table View and I think my functions are running in the wrong order.

I have a simple function loadSampleAssignments() that populates an array. If I call that function directly in viewDidLoad my table populates correctly.

The problem is that I need to call the code after a successful response from Auth0 in this code:

```
fileprivate func retrieveProfile() {
    guard let accessToken = loginCredentials.accessToken else { return }
    Auth0
        .authentication()
        .userInfo(token: accessToken)
        .start { result in
            switch result {
            case .success( _):
                self.loadSampleAssignments()
            case .failure( _): break
            }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I call the function here my UI updates with an empty array. I can see that loadSampleAssignments() is called, but it is after my cellForRowAt function has updated the table cells.

Is there a way I can manually call the cellForRowAt function inside my loadSampleAssignments function?

I have been stuck for days, and would really appreciate any help on this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point where you're ready for the table to be repopulated, call `tableView.reloadData()`, which will trigger `cellForRow`.  It is not a problem that `cellForRow` also gets triggered before the data is ready to display -- this is normal and doesn't mean you're doing anything wrong.

Comment: You're a wizard! That did it!I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you so much! Very glad to know that is normal behavior.